# Forcing functions to accept types only, and not the underlying types of the type

Tags: go, struct, enums

How do I make sure that a function accepts only the defined type and not the underlying type of this type?

I defined my pseudo-enums as following:

```golang
type Method string

var Methods = struct {
    GET   Method
    POST  Method
    PATCH Method
}{
    GET:   "GET",
    POST:  "POST",
    PATCH: "PATCH",
}
```

and using them in the following fashion (simplified):

```golang
func getRequest(method Method) (*http.Request, error) {
    return http.NewRequest(string(method), "some_random_path", nil)
}

func main() {
    _, _ = getRequest(Methods.GET) // This is the intended use
    _, _ = getRequest("GET")       // Why is this allowed?
}
```

Why is the compiler not complaining about using `"GET"` string literal where `Method` type is required?
How can I change my code so that a string literal cannot be used where type Method is required?

Comment: "Why is the compiler not complaining about using "GET" string literal where Method type is required?" Because the language spec says so: Untyped constants are converted. "How can I change my code so that a string literal cannot be used where type Method is required?" Buraks method works but is dead ugly. You should _keep_ the code as is. It is fine Go code.

Comment: Thank you, Volker! That clarifies a lot. I will probably continue using this method as you advised in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"GET"` is an untyped constant. If an untyped constant can be converted to the underlying type, then it is converted to that type.  In the example:

```
 _, _ = getRequest("GET")
```

here, `"GET"` is of type `Method`, not `string`. The following would not be allowed:

```
s:="GET"
getRequest(s)
```

Because here, `s` is a `string`, not a `Method`.

If you need absolute enum-like type safety, you can try something like this:

```
type Method struct{v string}

var Methods = struct {
    GET   Method
    POST  Method
    PATCH Method
}{
    GET:   Method{v:"GET"},
    POST:  Method{v:"POST"},
    PATCH: Method{v:"PATCH"},
}
```

However, this is ugly, and usually not worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you, Burak! I will use your method when I need absolute type safety. It makes total sense that the struct with a single field is the simplest form of an "enforced" enum.

Comment: @IvanD keep in mind, using strings for enums is just fine. The perceived benefits of such type-safety usually don't materialize for most practical cases.

Comment: Indeed, as Burak points out, it is extraordinarily unlikely that that level of type safety is worth the cost in complexity and readability. If you think you need this, I would look very, very closely at what you're doing, because you probably really don't need it.

Comment: Thank you, @Adrian! I agree that in this case it's probably an overkill as `http.NewRequest` will return an error if it receives anything but a valid request type like GET, POST, etc. How would you approach the task of limiting the options of what can be used as an argument then in idiomatic Go?

Comment: The best resource for examples of "idiomatic go" is the standard library. For example, here's how the stdlib does exactly that: https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=26884:26953#L838